# ReactJS subdomains with Apache (or NGINX)... should I use separate apps/React Router config?

Tags: apache, reactjs, nginx, subdomain

I am building an app that will have a public site of www.mywebsite.com and an admin/staff app of admin.mywebsite.com. The app(s) are being built using ReactJS with React Router 4 and will have a PHP backend sitting on a server running either Apache or NGINX. The public and admin apps will for all intents and purposes be entirely different apps. I am trying to find out how this can be done and the best practice.

So I am aware that I establish the subdomain for React Router using just plain old JS: -

```
const [subdomain] = window.location.hostname.split('.')
```

However, I am confused at to whether this should be done on the server level or left to ReactJS? As the 2 apps are essentially entirely different app, should I just create separate entry points for them such as index.html and admin.html?

I hope my question isn't too vague... I've never worked with subdomains before and this is my first app using ReactJS.